# Importar LateX para o R Markdown

Tags: r, latex

Olá! Provavelmente esta dúvida já foi abordada aqui mas eu não encontrei... Bem utilizo o R Markdonw para gerar manuais sobre determinados comandos do R, porém fiz um diagrama no LateX e queria saber se existe alguma forma de importar o mesmo para o R Markdown. Obrigado!

Gostaria de inserir isto.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bch} % change default font
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{figure}[h]       
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        [% style definitions
        ,every node/.style={node distance=3, font=\footnotesize}
        ,comment/.style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily}
        ,force/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=black!10, inner sep=5pt, text width=3cm, text badly centered, minimum height=1.2cm, font=\bfseries\footnotesize\sffamily}
        ,on grid
        ] 
        % Draw forces
        \node [force] (z) {Dados Arvore};
        \node [force, above = of z] (y) {Dados Originais};
        \node [force, right = 5 of z] (x) {Secção};
        \node [force, below = of z] (v) {Dados Arvore II};
        \node [force, right = 5 of v] (b) {Cubagem};
        \node [force, below = 4 of v] (w) {Arquivo Final};
        \node [force, below left = 2 and 2.5 of v] (c) {Modelos de Relaçao Hisométrica};
        \node [force, below right = 2 and 2.5 of v] (e) {Modelos de Volume};        
        % Draw the links between forces
        \path[->,thick,every node/.append style={comment,anchor=base, fill=white}] 
        (y) edge node {Avaliação} (z) edge node {Avaliação} (x)
        (z) edge node {Inconsistências e Manipulação} (v)
        (v) edge (w) edge node {Ajuste} (c) edge node {Ajuste} (e)
        (c) edge node {Predição} (w)
        (e) edge node {Predição} (w)
        (x) edge node {Inconsistências e Manipulação} (b)
        (b) edge node {Manipulação} (e);        
        \end{tikzpicture} 
        \caption[Diagrama do Script de ajuste de relação hipsométrica]{Diagrama do Script de ajuste de relação hipsométrica, volume cubado e equações de volumetria da empresa FLORESTECA.}
        \label{fig:6forces}
    \end{figure}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Talvez seja mais fácil você transformar seu RMarkdown em Latex, isso serve?

Comment: Os arquivos RMarkdown aceitam comandos LaTeX diretamente, você já tentou colocar dessa forma? Por exemplo, coloque `$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$` em um documento e faça o Knit.

Comment: Olá, editei minha pergunta.

Answer (score 3):

Presumo que estejas a usar `pandoc doc.rmd -o doc.pdf`
ou semelhante.

O ficheiro `Rmarkdown` precisa de um bloco de metadata (sugiro que colocado no início do documento, e neste caso vou usar `YAML`)
onde incluas os headear de `LateX/tikz`

```
---
title: "Manual de ...."
date: \today
header-includes:
    - \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bch}
    - \usepackage{tikz}
    - \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
---

Diagrama em TiKZ
================

\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        [% style definitions
        ,every node/.style={node distance=3, font=\footnotesize}
        ,comment/.style={font=\scriptsize\sffamily}
        ....
        ....
\end{figure}
```

Era isto que precisavas? (cortar o que não interessa)

Isto funciona bem para construir pdf, e alguns outros formatos. Para outros
casos (Ex. HTML) é preciso mais trabalho -- Ver tambem `pandocfilters`.

Comment: Descobri, depois de muitos testes, que isso só funciona para fazer o knit de pdfs, pois pelo que entendi o documento é enviado novamente para o programa de LaTeX que interpreta corretamente o código TeX. Para HTML e Word, nada aparece.

Comment: @Molx, eu sou um ignorante nesta matéria mas o pandoc permite milagres: dá é trabalho... Para teres tikz em html é preciso converter os extractos em imagens; isso em pandac passa pelos `pandocfilters` -- no fundo um programa que extrai as partes, converte, inclui os resultados. Por exemplo em  http://blog.twshodgson.co.uk/2014/12/14/diagrams-with-tikz-using-pandoc-filters/ tem um exemplo deste género.

Comment: Interessante. Eu fiz os testes dentro do RStudio, utilizando o botão `Knit`, e por isso acho que as opções são mais limitadas. Mas não tenho experiência com LaTeX e pouca com Rmd, até ontem nem sabia o que era Pandoc...

Comment: @molx, e eu confesso que não conheço o RStudio... O RStudio existe em linux? (quase de certeza que ele está a usar LeTeX por baixo. CUriosamente o pandoc está escrito em Haskell!